# importance of "Identity" in Category theory

Tags: category-theory

Reading about category theory a category is a collection of objects "types" that have morphisms "transformations" with two properties:

Associativity: for every object all its morphisms should be associative when composed together.
Identity: for every object must have one identity morphism which doesn't change any of his other morphisms when it is composed with them.
So associativity seems like a reasonable property that ensures correct composition.

but why is identity important? what purpose does it serve? and why is it called "identity" and not just "neutral morphism"? And why do some categories like "magma, semigroup" don't have identity or associativity but are still called categories?

for anyone else that comes here:
ignore this link [purpose of identity morphism](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-purpose-of-identity-morphisms-in-category-theory)
and go directly to this link [The Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464533/on-the-identity-map-requirement-in-the-definition-of-category)

> it is possible to define isomorphisms without identities, but it is a
> bit more complicated and less elegant. I think you're reading far too
> much into Eilenberg and Mac Lane: they weren't trying to make some
> "universal" definition that applies to every situation imaginable;
> they were just making a natural-seeming definition that works in all
> the relevant examples they could think of."
>
> Considering "associative" operations which don't have identities is
> thus analogous to considering finite sets but not allowing the empty
> set. Of course, this is sometimes useful to do, but unless you have a
> good reason to, it is probably not the natural thing to do.

Thank you PrudiiArca for your help and special thanks to Eric Wofsey for the answer

Comment: For one thing, isomorphism is an idea of fundamental importance in category theory, and one needs identity morphisms to formulate it properly.

Comment: can you please give an example? do you mean for comparing if two categories are the "same"?

Comment: Thanks alot Eric, please put your link so i can mark it as the answer

Comment: The proof of yoneda lemma relies on the existence of identities. Moreover, if we interpret arrows as in some vague way acting on their domain objects having to preserve some structure on the domains, then I surely want the “trivial” action to be there, just as the identity map is always a symmetry in all sensible contexts, i.e. identity is always in Aut(A) for any mathematical object (i.e., set withe extra structure), and Aut(A) being the set of symmetries of A relative to this structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do confuse things here.

A category is a mathematical structure, which generalizes the well known pattern „sets with structure + structure preserving maps“. In all the instances e.g. vector spaces + vector space homomorphisms/ groups + group homomorphisms/ measure spaces and measurable functions etc. etc. the composition of functions is associative, so it is natural to have associativity as an axiom. Moreover in all instances, the easiest structure preserving map you can think of is the identity function on your object, which literally does nothing and hence is structure preserving. Since all examples, which we want to generalize come with identities, we introduce an axiom of having identity morphisms for each object. You are wrong in saying that categories of magmas or semigroups dont have identities. They do have them, since as I explained the identity function on a magma/semigroup does not interfer with the structure and hence is structure preserving.

Now one notices that the concept of a category is more powerful than just describing these examples. For example one notices that certain structures like groups or monoids can be expressed in purely categorical terms as one object category, whose morphisms represent the elements and satisfy some axioms with respect to composition, which is given by the group operation. This is the point, were you cannot express magmas or semigroups in categorical terms, because a magma needs not be associative and a semigroup doesn’t have to have identities.

Comment: so from your answer and some reading so far: identity is the simplest structure preserving map, structure preserving maps in 2 directions means we have isomorphism between 2 structures. having identity morphism allows us to know which morphisms can be composed together, if 2 morphisms have same identity morphism then they can be composed together; so for morphism f,g and identity morphism i, if we use "." as composition symbol if "f.i=f" and "g.i=g" so they have same identity so we can compose f and g, is this correct?

Comment: No it’s not. Composition has nothing to do with identities a priory. What is your background in math? Categories can be explained best, if one knows which examples can be made...

Comment: actually i'm programmer trying to understand theoretical background for functional programming, i'm trying to understand category theory in my free time :), i just wanted to understand why "identity" is a fundamental axiom, i found link here "https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-purpose-of-identity-morphisms-in-category-theory" where "Andrew Winkler, PhD Mathematics" said identity "define composability" but i'm still not sure i understand it

Comment: Well then this Winkler and I both were not careful enough with our wording. Identities are part of the data of a category. It has objects, morphisms with a dedicated source and target, dedicated identity morphisms and a composition function. This is all the data, but we have to force some axioms. Morphisms are composable, if the target of the first one is the source of the second one. This is why I meant composition has a priori nothing to do with identities. However another axiom tells you that the identities act with respect to composition like identities, so a posteriori they do relate to

Comment: composition. Now regarding your background you may really think of identities as „do nothing transformations on types“. The word transformation is bad though, as it is used elsewhere in category theory.

Comment: i understand it does nothing, my problem is if it does nothing then why is it important? what does "defines composability" means? does it mean really mean 2 morphisms need to have same identity morphism to be composable or what?

Comment: @anonymous: I would suggest that you completely ignore what Andrew Winkler wrote.  It is a minor curiosity that is irrelevant to understanding what categories are and why identities are important, and is mostly just misleading to someone at your level.

Comment: Well lets say you want to express the following in type theory: the integers can be considered as rational numbers and rounding of rational numbers gives you integers. Now how would you (just using morphisms and composition!) express the fact, that if you round an integer, considered as a rational number, nothing happens?

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider how the definitions reduce in the simple case when the category has exactly one object. Then the axioms of a category are equivalent to the axioms of a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Definition) on the set of morphisms of the category. This is because monoids have only two axioms: associativity and existence of identity element. This identity element corresponds precisely to the identity morphism of the one object in the category. Thus, the purpose served by the identity morphism is precisely the same as the purpose served by the identity element in a monoid. In this sense, one can say that category theory is a generalization of the theory of monoids.

You mentioned magmas and semigroups in your question - these are what we get from a monoid by first removing the identity axiom (semigroups) and then removing the associativity axiom (magmas) leaving something that is very unstructured. We can consider categories whose objects are magmas or semigroups, with the appropriate notion of morphism. And we can also say that a category with a single object has morphisms which form a monoid, and therefore is a special kind of semigroup and magma. But we cannot say that an arbitrary semigroup or magma is equal to the morphism set of some category with one object.

Note that one could generalize the definition of a category to be built upon semigroups or magmas instead of monoids, simply by removing axioms. We could call the resulting generalizations a "catsemigroup" and a "catmagma" for example. Then categories would be special kinds of "catsemigroups" and "catsemigroups" would be special kinds of "catmagmas". But not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you pre-kidney, weird name BTW :)